# Install MSI package for non-admin users

Tags: windows-installer, non-admin

we have requirement to create a MSI package to run on non-admin users machine.

i have created msi package using wixedit tool and works perfectly for Admin users and not for non-admin users.

is there any config settings in wixedit to run and install the MSI package for non-admin users?

our application will install in program files directory location and our end users doesn't have privileges to run the msi as administrator

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `our application will install in program files directory location ` - Then it cannot be installed as a non-admin user.  A non-admin user cannot write to program files.  Packages installed by non-admin users are installed to the users profile (eg c:\users\%username).

Answer (score 3):

There's no way around it. Preventing users from installing software on their own is the whole point of not giving users local admin rights in the first place.

The only way to do the install is to use a package distribution system (e.g. SCCM, Kaseya, psexec, Remote Installer, etc.) that can elevate privileges.

If the computers in question are on a domain and you don't have access to such tools, then Group Policy would be your best bet.

[This link can get you started](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816102)

Comment: There is also the AlwaysInstallElevated option (Google it), but any admin would probably be nuts to enable it. I include it here for completeness.

Comment: Wow I've been working with Group Policy for years and I can't believe I've never seen that setting! Probably because my brain subconsciously realized how ridiculous it is and ignored it.